# Creating THREE pickerViews for converting the units

Tags: swift3, ios10, units-of-measurement

Here is the main screen of the app :

[image]

I have successfully linked these pickerView to each other, then I have tried to assign the calculation in converting but not to avail :

ex:  mile to killo
but I could not find a way to do so. I have tried to use "Switch" still nothing happen. I just need someone can show me how can I convert from a certain unit to another unit through the textFields. For example, if you enter a value in a certain texField the converted result will in the other textField and vise versa.

Here is my Code:

```
    import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate{

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var leftPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var rightPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldLeft: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFielfRight: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var equal: UILabel!


var leftPickerData : [String] = []
var rightPickerData : [String] = []

var dataDict:NSMutableDictionary!
var mainPickerData:NSArray!
var leftRightPickerData:NSArray!

//yourPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "back.jpg")!)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mainPicker.backgroundColor = .clear
    rightPicker.backgroundColor = .clear
    leftPicker.backgroundColor = .clear

    // Connect data to ViewController ..
    self.mainPicker.delegate = self
    self.mainPicker.dataSource = self

    self.leftPicker.delegate = self
    self.leftPicker.dataSource = self

    self.rightPicker.delegate = self
    self.rightPicker.dataSource = self

    self.textFieldLeft.delegate = self
    self.textFielfRight.delegate = self

    let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
    let theHeight = view.frame.size.height

    mainPicker.center = CGPoint(x: theWidth/2, y: theHeight/2 - 182.5)
    leftPicker.center = CGPoint(x: theWidth/2 - 100, y: theHeight/2)
    rightPicker.center = CGPoint(x: theWidth/2 + 100, y: theHeight/2)
    textFieldLeft.center = CGPoint(x: theWidth/2 - 90, y: theHeight/2 + 110)
    textFielfRight.center = CGPoint(x: theWidth/2 + 90, y: theHeight/2 + 110)
    equal.center = CGPoint(x: theWidth/2, y: theHeight/2 + 110)



    dataDict = ["Area":["Square Mile", "Square Yard", "Square Foot", "Square Inch", "Hectare", "Acre", "Square Kilometer", "Square Meter", "Square Centimeter", " Square Millimeter"]
        ,"Energy":["Btus", "Calories", "Ergs", "Foot-Pounds", "Joules", "Kilogram-Calories", "Kilogram-Meters", "Kilowatt-Hours", "Newton-Meters", "Watt-Hours"], "Length":["Mile", "Yard", "Foot", "Inch", "Kilometer", "Meter", "Centimeter", "Millimeter"], "Power": ["Btus/Minute", "Foot-Pounds/Min", "Foot-Pounds/Sec", "Horsepower", "Kilowatts", "Watts"], "Pressure": ["Pounds/Sqr Ft", "Pounds/Sqr In", "Atmospheres", "Bars", "In of Mercury", "Cm of Mercury", "Kilograms/Sqr Meter", "Pascals"], "Speed": ["Knots", "Miles/Hr", "Miles/Min", "Feet/Min", "Feet/Sec", "Kilometers/Hr", "Kilometer/Min", "Meters/Sec"], "Temperature": ["Celsius C˚", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin"], "Time": ["Years", "Months", "Weeks", "Days", "Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds", "Millisconds", "Microseconds", " Nanoseconds"], "Volume": ["Cupic Feet","Cubic Meter", "Gallon (Imp)", "Gallon (US)", "Quart (US)", "Pint (US)", "Fluid Oz", "Cup", "Tablespoon", "Teaspoon", "Dram (US)", "Liter"], "Weight": ["Short Ton (US)","Long Ton (UK)", "Pound (U.S)", "Ounce (US)", "Stone", "Metric Ton", "Kilogram", "Gram"]]
    mainPickerData = dataDict.allKeys as NSArray!;
    leftRightPickerData = dataDict.object(forKey: mainPickerData.firstObject as! String) as! NSArray

    // Linking the textFields with the pickerViews.
    //textFieldLeft.inputView = leftPicker;
   // textFielfRight.inputView = rightPicker;



    }



// The number of columns of data
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// The number of rows of data
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    switch (pickerView.tag) {

    case mainPicker.tag:

        return mainPickerData.count

    case leftPicker.tag,rightPicker.tag:

        let currentSelectedIndex = mainPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: component)
        leftRightPickerData = (dataDict.object(forKey: mainPickerData[currentSelectedIndex] as! String) as! NSArray)

        return leftRightPickerData.count;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if leftPicker.tag == 2 {

        return leftPickerData[row]

    }else if rightPicker.tag == 3{

        return rightPickerData[row]

    }

    return ""
}

// Catpure the picker view selection
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
    // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.

    if(pickerView.tag == 1 ){

        let currentSelectedIndex = mainPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: component)
        leftRightPickerData = (dataDict.object(forKey: mainPickerData[currentSelectedIndex] as! String) as! NSArray)

        leftPicker.reloadAllComponents()
        rightPicker.reloadAllComponents()

        if mainPicker.tag == mainPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: component) {

            if leftPicker.tag == leftPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: component) && rightPicker.tag == rightPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: component){

                textFieldLeft.text = textFielfRight.text
            }
        }

    }



}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textFieldLeft.resignFirstResponder()
    textFielfRight.resignFirstResponder()

    return true

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let titleData : String?
    if(pickerView.tag == mainPicker.tag){
        titleData = mainPickerData[row] as? String;

    }
    else{

        let currentSelectedIndex = mainPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        leftRightPickerData = (dataDict.object(forKey: mainPickerData[currentSelectedIndex] as! String) as! NSArray)

        titleData = leftRightPickerData[row] as? String;
    }

    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 12.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blue])
    return myTitle;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this as an example for different length values:

You would want to store some sort of array that tracks conversion values for each different unit of measurement, the best universal length unit is meters. It would be a good idea to make sure the corresponding value for each unit stays static, so create an `enum`:

```
enum Length: Int {
    case mile           = 0
    case yard           = 1
    case foot           = 2
    case inch           = 3
    case kilometer      = 4
    // ... keep going with all lenght units of measurement
}
```

Then you should make your array of values for conversions, this is an array of double's based on the length values I listed in the `enum` above for conversion to `meters`:

```
// Store values with corresponding indicies in array to the Length enum's values
let meterConversions:[Double] = [1609.34, 0.9144, 0.3048, 0.0254, 1,000]

// Store values of length unit descriptions to print after conversion in TextField, long hand or short hand whatever you prefer. (this is optional)
let lengthUnits = ["Mile", "Yard", "Foot", "Inch", "Kilometer"]
```

Then create some conversion methods:

```
// Convert length type to meters
func convertToMeters(type: Length, unitValue: Double) -> Double {
    return (meterConversions[type.rawValue] * unitValue)
}

// Convert meters back to length type
func convertFromMeters(type: Length, meterValue: Double) -> Double {
    return meterValue/meterConversions[type.rawValue]
}

// Convert from length type to other length type
func convertType(from: Length, to: Length, unitValue: Double) -> Double {

    // Convert from value to meters to start
    let fromValueToMeters:Double = convertToMeters(type: from, unitValue: unitValue)

    // Now use that value to convert back to desired unit
    let newUnitValue:Double = convertFromMeters(type: to, meterValue: fromValueToMeters)

    return newUnitValue
}
```

Then whenever the user selects a new row in either the left or right `UIPickerView`, update the calculation and handle it however you wish:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    // Make sure there is actually some text in the left text field, otherwise return
    guard let text = textFieldLeft.text else { print("textFieldLeft doesn't contain any text"); return }

    // You are going to need a numerical (Double) value from the user's text
    let stringAsDouble = Double(text)

    // Now check that the text was actually a numerical value able to be converted to a double
    if let value = stringAsDouble {

        var typeA:Length!
        var typeB:Length!

        if pickerView == leftPicker {
            typeA = Length(rawValue: row)!
            typeB = Length(rawValue: rightPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0))!
            converted = convertType(from: typeA, to: typeB, unitValue: value)
        }
        else if pickerView == rightPicker {
            typeA = Length(rawValue: leftPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0))!
            typeB = Length(rawValue: row)!
            let value:Double = 0 // Determine user entered value from textField
            converted = convertType(from: typeA, to: typeB, unitValue: value)
        }

        updateValueAfterConversion(originalValue: value, originalType: typeA, convertedValue: converted, convertedType: typeB)
    } else {
        print("Couldn't convert text to double value")
    }
}

func updateValueAfterConversion(originalValue: Double, originalType: Length, convertedValue: Double, convertedType: Length) {
    // Update text in both fields, lengthUnits part is optional if you want to print unit along with value.
    // Update text on left side
    textFieldLeft.text = "\(originalValue) \(lengthUnits[originalType.rawValue])"
    // Update text on right side
    textFieldRight.text = "\(convertedValue) \(lengthUnits[convertedType.rawValue])"
}
```

Comment: What did you mean for your last comment :

// Now do whatever you want with converted value

Comment: @Turki M. Alsayed - Then you would have the inputted value converted from the unit type in pickerA to unit type in pickerB. So lets say the user requested conversion of 10 feet to inches. Your `converted` variable should have a value of `120.0` - you could then update the `UITextField` or whatever label you want to use to update the UI to alert user as to converted value. For example: `textField.text = "Converted Value: \(converted)"` or if it's a label: `label.text = "Converted Value: \(converted)"`, etc...

Comment: Hello Mr. Pierce,

I have done exactly what you explained above, I did only for "LENGTH" to make sure I'm following the right path. Unfortunately, when I pick any thing from subLength ex: inch I got "Nan" in the textfield from both left and right. 

I did the following :

Your cooperation is highly appreciate it.

if (textFieldLeft.text?.isEmpty)! {
            
            textFieldLeft.text = "\(converted)"
        }else{
            
            textFielfRight.text = "\(converted)"
        }

Comment: @TurkiM.Alsayed - I will again update my answer, at least so you can solve the Length section, but you're going to have to take the concept and apply it to all different types of measurement. It's probably going to take a little bit of work

Comment: @TurkiM.Alsayed - Okay I updated my answer again for you. Now this should completely help you solve the "Length" portion of your problem. You're going to have to do the same process for each conversion type, and you'll have to do the research into conversion charts and what not. Please accept my answer if it works for you

Comment: Mr.Pierce,

I just did exactly what you told to do, but nothing happen. I added your updated code with my old code within func didSelectRow but nothing happen.

I felt from your last reply your were certain. If you do not mind would double check my old code all the way up.

Thank you

Comment: @TurkiM.Alsayed - Please re-copy and paste the updated `didSelectRowAt` method I just re-wrote in my answer into your project. Then run your app and tell me what is printed out in the console. I added some `print` commands to help debug the issue

Comment: Hello again,

I have updated didSelectRowAt , When I select any title from the main pickerView the left & right had updated. I notice when I pick any title from any pickerView (main, left, and right) I got this message: 

"Couldn't convert text to double value"

When I click inside any of the textField I got this message:

"Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 1316927560_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
"

this is the only two messages I got ... if you need a picture or recording I would gladly do it.

thank you

Comment: @TurkiMAlsayed - I put that code in there to let me know what was happening. That tells me that the value you are entering in the left hand textfield isn't a number, or isn't a complete number. Try typing in something like `1234.0` and then moving either the left picker or the right picker

Comment: You really should change that to convert on the tap of a button, but I was just showing you based on what you had

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some tips:

1. Value in a text field is a String, you should convert it to Double and then multiply by different value between 2 units.
2. To save these different values, I have an idea: save [1, 1760, 5280, 63360, 1.609344, 1609.344, 160934.4, 1609344] for ["Mile", "Yard", "Foot", "Inch", "Kilometer", "Meter", "Centimeter", "Millimeter"] then do some math caculating.
3. You should listen to the notification UITextFieldTextDidChange for each UITextField to instantly calculate the equal value.

If you are a lazy developer, I found this for you: https://github.com/michalkonturek/MKUnits

Hope this helps.